# Entity Framework creates new record instead of "linking to" existing record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

[image: Database]

I am using `IdentityModels` to add some extra data to my `ApplicationUser` (`UserProperties`).

Here's the UserProperties class:

```
    public UserProperties()
    {
        Region = new Region();
        Universe = new Universe();
    }

    public int UserPropertiesId { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public Universe Universe { get; set; }
```

The issue at hand is that whenever the user creates an account, they must select a region and a universe, but instead of "linking" the region and universe to the UserProperties' entries, Entity Framework creates *new* entires in Universes and Regions, even though the IDs supplied to the AccountController for the region and universe **are correct** (i.e. they exist in the DB).

How can I fix this?

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is in the `UserProperties` constructor where you create *new* instances of `Region` and `Universe`. Those entities are detatched from your datacontext. Therefore when you call `SaveChanges` and entity framework sees that your userproperty has two detached related entities it assumes that they need to be created. [More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

You need to either

1. Manually attach the region and universe to your datacontext like this `context.Regions.Attach(myRegion);`.
2. Load the region and universe from the datacontext so that they are attached.
3. Add the foreign key properties to `UserProperties` then set them instead of the actual entities.

I would go with 3. I find that having the foreign key properties available is always useful.

You will also need to remove the initialization from your contructor or else it will keep creating new regions and universes every time you save a UserProperties. < insert string theory joke >

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public int UserPropertiesId { get; set; }
public int RegionId{get;set;}//should be the key of Region table
public Region Region { get; set; }
public int UniverseId{get;set;}//should be the key of Universe table
public Universe Universe { get; set; }
```

This should do the linking.

Take a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) blog

Comment: But why is this necessary when both Universe and Region has their own IDs? (UniverseId and RegionId)