# Entity Framework ASP.NET MVC6 in Identity Model, Creating a new record instead of linking it to existing record

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Someone posted the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393688/entity-framework-creates-new-record-instead-of-linking-to-existing-record?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and I followed every step and yet it still doesn't work. I made many working projects before with the same feature.

So when a user registers for a new account, he fills out a form and Selects from 2 dropdownlists UserType and Region.

everything else works fine and when the form is posted. a new record of Region and UserType is created in the DB and linked with new IDs.

here is my IdentityModel:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }

    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Summoner Name")]
    public string SummonerName { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> 
    GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    // etc.....
```

here is my Register Action in AccountController

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var UserTypeInDb = _context.UserTypes.Single(u => u.Id == model.UserTypeId);
            var RegionInDb = _context.Regions.Single(u => u.Id == model.RegionId);


            var user = new ApplicationUser {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                Name = model.Name,
                Region = RegionInDb,
                UserType = UserTypeInDb
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel()
        {
            Regions = _context.Regions.ToList(),
            UserTypes = _context.UserTypes.ToList()
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

the 2 variables UserTypeInDb and RegionInDb contain the right records with the correct IDs.

so what is wrong exactly? and thanks

Comment: Why are you querying the database to add the object when you can just specify the Id?

Comment: When it was not working I had to debug it and created those two vars to make sure they had the right ID, but yeah you are right though i should remove it.

Comment: The part with "if we got this far...", you do not need to get the `Regions` and `UserTypes` again because you should already have it. Furthermore, you do not need to get the `UserTypeInDb` and `RegionInDb` from the databse. You have that already too.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it without changing ApplicationUser Class

```
            var user = new ApplicationUser {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email,
            RegionId = RegionInDb.Id,      <------- 
            UserTypeId = UserTypeInDb.Id,  <------- the fix
            UserType = UserTypeInDb
        };
```

Comment: You do not need `RegionInDb` or `UserTypeInDb`.